# Can .NET Core AWS VPC Lambda connect to On-prem SQL Server using Windows Authentication?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

AWS Microsoft Directory Services has been setup with outgoing trust relationship to on-prem domain. How to make a .NET Core AWS VPC Lambda talk to on-prem SQL Server using Windows Authentication?

I got a Python VPC Lambda working using pymssql package but I am trying to get .NET Core Lambda working similarly.